# Entity Framework refuses to save value on new column

Tags: entity-framework

I just changed our database, adding a new column to a table and setting it as a foreign key. We're using EF4 Database first, so I updated the model from the DB, added my new field to the DTOs and everything looked great until I tried to save data to it.

The new column is called DiaryEventId, and because it's a FK there's also a virtual property on the object called DiaryEvent. Here's what the code looks like:

```
    public void SaveDocument(Guid CaseId, string diaryText, string ActivityType)
    {
        Guid eventTypeId = RepositoryHelper.GetDiaryEventFromCache("Document Uploaded", _commonQueryContext);
        //this wanders off and created a diary event object, adds it to 
        //the context and returns its ID
        Guid diaryId = RepositoryHelper.AuditEvent(CaseId, diaryText, commonUpdateContext);

        Entities.DocumentMetadata docData = new Entities.DocumentMetadata()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();,
            ActivityType = activityType,
            DiaryEventId = diaryId
        };

        _commonUpdateContext.DocumentMetadatas.Add(docData);
        _commonUpdateContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This compiles and runs fine, and when you step through it it appears to function as expected - diaryId is generated and set on the object. But in the DB, it always appears as null.

I've tried calling SaveChanges after adding the diary event (to make sure the key has something to connect to) and I've tried adding the actual DiaryEvent object to the virtual property rather than just the ID - both have the same effect.

When I watch what's going on in SQL Profiler, I can see that the INSERT statement simply ignores my new column completely - it's not listed in the insert columns at all.

Really got no idea what's going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the object after adding it to the context, just as a test.

```
    _commonUpdateContext.DocumentMetadatas.Add(docData);

    Entities.DocumentMetadata docData = new Entities.DocumentMetadata()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();,
        ActivityType = activityType,
        DiaryEventId = diaryId
    };

    _commonUpdateContext.SaveChanges();
```

Or is this perhaps a typo?

```
Entities.DocumentMetadata docData = new Entities.DocumentMetadata()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();,  <-------------typo?
```

Beyond that, it will require a bit of info on how you have your entities mapped out. Is there a navigation property between DiaryEvent and DocumentMetadata? Is the key defined as nullable (I'm assuming it is)? Is ActivityType getting persisted correctly?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - modifying as suggested has no effect.

Comment: Heh, no it's not that. That's me mangling my actual code into something briefer to demonstrate the problem.